# Display once in a while loop, hide show, sql, php

Tags: php, html, sql, formatting

I want to display something like

**1** John

**2** Mary

**3** David

After clicking ID, then

**1** John

eventname:ABC

eventname:DEF

eventname:GHI

**2** Mary

eventname:DEF

**3** David

eventname: null

```
$n=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{   
    if ($lastId != $row[0]){
        echo "<strong><a href='javascript:ReverseDisplay(" . ($row[0]) . ")'>" . $row[0] . "</a></strong>"; 
        echo urldecode($row[1])." ";    
        echo urldecode($row[2])." ";

        echo "<br>";
        echo ($n == 0) ? "<div id=" . ($row[0]) . " style='display:none;'>" : "";
    }

        echo mysql_field_name($rs,16) . ":" . urldecode($row[16]);
        echo "<br>";    


    if ($lastId != $row[0]){    
        echo ($n == 0) ? '</div>' : '';

    }       
    $lastId = $row[0];
    $n++;   
}
```

I know there are something wrong with it, but couldn't fix it. Could someone give a helping hand? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Also having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?